# Trigonometric functions over arbitrary angles

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Trigonometric functions over obtuse or arbitrary angles doesn't make sense. We can only imagine for eg. sin(x) for angles < 90 degrees because it represents the ratio of the opposite and hypotenuse. Now, from nowhere, we define it for arbitrary angles. I know that these are functions and for an input they produce an output and we can define them as we want. Were is the freedom from to define them the way they're defined(we all know that) and they can be still useful? I know my questions is a little confusing but, this really doesn't make sense if we stick to the intuition.

Comment: No, to *stick* to intuition in science and mathematics is a very, very bad idea. This is, or should be, high school stuff, where the trigonometric circle and the trigonometric function's generalization is explained.

Comment: I don't know you understand my question. I understand both, the trigonometric circle and the trigonometric function's generalization but, i don't understand _why_ they are generalized that way and how can they still be aplicable. I think I am clear now.

Comment: To me the intuition to stick to about the sine is "the $y$ coordinate of the point so-and-so far around the unit circle", which make perfect sense for all angles. The fact that the restriction to a limited range of angles can _also_ be used to calculate things in certain right triangles is a useful _property_ of the sine, but not what the sine "really is".

Comment: With the definition over arbitrary angles we get just a _way_, a _rule_ which can given input transform to some output. But that doesn't mean anything. When we have a right triangle, we can clearly see what sine means and that is a ratio. When we define it for arbitrary angles we just get a pair of values. The first number is the input to the sine function and the second is the output. Again, the question is: How we can make these generalizations and trigonometric functions can still be aplicable?

Answer (score 0):

The standard definitions of sin and cos for angles outside the range $0^\circ \le \theta \le 90^\circ$ make really pretty graphs that provide a good model for things like sound waves and alternating current.  Also, they provide analytic functions which have such great things like a Taylor's series.  Also they satisfy Euler's formula $e^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)$.  And then there are Fourier series which are absolutely indispensable to a great deal of science, engineering and math, which totally rely on these definitions of sin and cos.